# Symfony2 ManyToOne duplicated

Tags: symfony, one-to-many, many-to-one, where-in

I have 2 entities. I would like to get a result like below. I tried this on my server:

"SELECT s.se_name, c.ca_name FROM service s inner join category c ON s.ca_id_id = c.id"

It's working fine. But now I would like to convert it to Symfony query. Without WHERE I got all of combination. How can I use WHERE on this situation?

```
+----+---------+         +----+---------+-------+
+ id + ca_name +         + id + se_name + ca_id +
+----+---------+         +----+---------+-------+        
+ 1  + A       +    +    + 1  + a1      + 1     +  =>  a1 .. A
+----+---------+         +----+---------+-------+      a2 .. A
+ 2  + B       +         + 2  + a2      + 1     +
+----+---------+         +----+---------+-------+
```

Service entity:

```
/**
* Service
*
* @ORM\Table(name="service")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ServiceRepository")
*/
class Service {
 ...

 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="services", cascade={"persist","remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
 private $caId;

 /**
 * Set caId
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Category $caId
 *
 * @return Service
 */
 public function setCaId(\AppBundle\Entity\Category $caId = null)
 {
     $this->caId = $caId;
     return $this;
 }

 /**
 * Get caId
 *
 * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Category
 */
 public function getCaId()
 {
     return $this->caId;
 }
}
```

Category entity:

```
/**
* Category
*
* @ORM\Table(name="category")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\CategoryRepository")
*/
class Category {
 ...

 /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(
 *   targetEntity="Service",
 *   mappedBy="caId"
 * )
 */
 private $services;

 /**
 * Constructor
 */
 public function __construct()
 {
   $this->services = new ArrayCollection();
 }

 /**
 * Get orders
 *
 * @return Collection
 */
 public function getServices()
 {
   return $this->services;
 }
}
```

ServiceRepository

```
   /**
   * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
   */
  public function getAllServices()
  {
    $qb = $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('s')
        ->select('c.caName, s.id, s.seName, s.sePrice')
        ->from('AppBundle:Category', 'c');
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use joins in Doctrine's query language too. In your repository you can do something like this:

```
public function getAllServices()
{
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery(
        'SELECT service
        FROM AppBundleService AS service
        INNER JOIN service.caId'
    );

    return $query->getResult();
}
```

You can achieve the same using the fluid interface of the query builder. But that doesn't add any value when the query itself is not built at runtime based on user input.

Comment: Hi xabbuh, it's nice to see you again. Your query didn't work really well. It returns me a service with empty category. I tried "SELECT
        s.seName, c.caName
      FROM
        AppBundle:Service s INNER JOIN AppBundle:Category c
      WHERE
        s.caId = c.id" and it's working fine now.

Comment: I don't see why that should happen with that query. The inner join ensures that there must be a category for the service. By the way, you where condition looks weird as you compare a `Category` entity (`s.caId`) with a scalar value (`c.id`).

Comment: I got something like this: array:1 [▼
  0 => Service {#628 ▼
    -id: 32
    -seName: "abc"
    -caId: Category {#650 ▼
      +__isInitialized__: false
      -id: 5
      -caName: null
      -services: null
       …2
    }
  }
]

Comment: OH :) I changed your query to symfony query and it's working fine now. "
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('s')
        ->select('s,c')
        ->join('s.caId', 'c')->getQuery()->getResult();"

Comment: Can you check my other problem, please? :D http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34565333/symfony2-deleteform-not-working-fine

Comment: How can I achieve caNumber on my Controller? Now I got: 0 => Service {#637 ▼
    -id: 37
    -seName: "a1"
    -caId: Category {#615 ▼
      -id: 2
      -caName: "A"
      -caNumber: 3
      -services: PersistentCollection {#641 ▶}
    }
  }

Comment: You can just use the methods provided by your entities like this: `$results[0]->getCatId()->getCaNumber()`