# symfony2 deleteForm not working fine

Tags: symfony, one-to-many, sql-delete, delete-row, many-to-one

I have 2 entities. I would like to delete row of Service.

I tried:

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

$service = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Service')->find(1);

$em->remove($service);

$em->flush();

On this way it deleted all of the row, which containing this category id. Sry for my bad English. Let me explain you on the other way:

```
           BEFORE                     AFTER delete id 1 from service
+----+------+  +----+------+-----+  +----+------+  +----+------+-----+
+ id + ca_  +  + id + se_  + ca_ +  + id + ca_  +  + id + se_  + ca_ +
+    + name +  +    + name + id  +  +    + name +  +    + name + id  +
+----+------+  +----+------+-----+  +----+------+  +----+------+-----+
+ 1  + A    +  + 1  + A1   + 1   +  +    +      +  +    +      +     +
+----+------+  +----+------+-----+  +----+------+  +----+------+-----+
+ 2  + B    +  + 2  + A2   + 1   +  + 2  + B    +  +    +      +     +
+----+------+  +----+------+-----+  +----+------+  +----+------+-----+
+ 3  + C    +  + 3  + B1   + 2   +  + 3  + C    +  + 3  + B1   + 2   +
+----+------+  +----+------+-----+  +----+------+  +----+------+-----+
```

How can I fixed that?

Service entity:

```
/**
* Service
*
* @ORM\Table(name="service")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ServiceRepository")
*/
class Service {
 ...

 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="services", cascade={"persist","remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
 private $caId;

 /**
 * Set caId
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Category $caId
 *
 * @return Service
 */
 public function setCaId(\AppBundle\Entity\Category $caId = null)
 {
     $this->caId = $caId;
     return $this;
 }

 /**
 * Get caId
 *
 * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Category
 */
 public function getCaId()
 {
     return $this->caId;
 }
}
```

Category entity:

```
/**
* Category
*
* @ORM\Table(name="category")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\CategoryRepository")
*/
class Category {
 ...

 /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(
 *   targetEntity="Service",
 *   mappedBy="caId"
 * )
 */
 private $services;

 /**
 * Constructor
 */
 public function __construct()
 {
   $this->services = new ArrayCollection();
 }

 /**
 * Get orders
 *
 * @return Collection
 */
 public function getServices()
 {
   return $this->services;
 }
}
```

---

Comment: Which category was assigned to the deleted service? And the second service entity was deleted to? Which category did it belong to?

Comment: I just updated my table. Check it, please. The second service was deleted to.

Comment: perhaps wrong mapping of ID entity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two issues with how your mapping is configured:

1. In your `Service` entity, you have configured to cascade removal operations. This means that when a `Service` object is deleted, the `Category` entity it was associated with will be deleted too.
2. The second crucial part in your mapping is the `@ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")`. On the database level this has the effect that when an entry from the `category` table is removed (which happens because of 1), every record in the `service` table that refers to the deleted category, will be deleted to (that's why the second service gets lost).

From looking at your model I assume that changing `cascade={"persist", "remove"}` in your `Service` entity to only `cascade={"persist"}` will be enough (maybe you even do not need to cascade persist operations).